# Get Duplicated Rows in Dataframe and Overwrite them Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe:

| index | errorId | start | end | timestamp | uniqueId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1404 | 2022-04-25 02:10:41 | 2022-04-25 02:10:46 | 2022-04-25 | 1404_2022-04-25 |
| 1 | 1302 | 2022-04-25 02:10:41 | 2022-04-25 02:10:46 | 2022-04-25 | 1302_2022-04-25 |
| 2 | 1404 | 2022-04-27 12:54:46 | 2022-04-27 12:54:51 | 2022-04-25 | 1404_2022-04-25 |
| 3 | 1302 | 2022-04-27 13:34:43 | 2022-04-27 13:34:50 | 2022-04-25 | 1302_2022-04-25 |
| 4 | 1404 | 2022-04-29 04:30:22 | 2022-04-29 04:30:29 | 2022-04-25 | 1404_2022-04-25 |
| 5 | 1302 | 2022-04-29 08:26:25 | 2022-04-29 08:26:32 | 2022-04-25 | 1302_2022-04-25 |

The unique_ID is a combination from the column errorId and uniqueId.
It should be checked whether the column 'uniqueID' contains a duplicate value. If this is the case, the row should be taken where it appears for the first time. In the example for errorId 1404, it would be the column at index 0. Afterwards, the value in the column 'end' should be overwritten with the value where it appears for the last time. In the example here, at index 4.
The same for errorId 1302

In the End it should look like this:

| index | errorId | start | end | timestamp | uniqueId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1404 | 2022-04-25 02:10:41 | 2022-04-29 04:30:29 | 2022-04-25 | 1404_2022-04-25 |
| 1 | 1302 | 2022-04-25 02:10:41 | 2022-04-29 08:26:32 | 2022-04-25 | 1302_2022-04-25 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need aggragate `min` and `max` per 3 columns with named aggregation, last for same order of columns like original add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['errorId','timestamp','uniqueId'], as_index=False, sort=False)
         .agg(start=('start','min'), end=('end','max'))
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
```

Or aggregate by `first` and `last`, if datetimes are sorted per groups get same ouput:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['errorId','timestamp','uniqueId'], as_index=False, sort=False)
         .agg(start=('start','first'), end=('end','last'))
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
```